# how to style boostrap element from within a php class?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a bootstrap alert from within php class. I have used echo inorder to use HTML tags. However, the alert displays at the buttom of the page, so how can I display the alert below the header.

```
 public function insert($userName,$email,$phone,$choise) {    

 $dhandller = "SELECT `email`, `phone` FROM `info` WHERE email = '$email' OR phone = '$phone' ";
  $statements = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($dhandller);  
 $statements->execute(); 

 if ($statements->fetch() >= 1){


echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' style='margin-top: 50px;'>";
echo "<strong>Danger!</strong> Your contact deatails are existsed";
echo "</div>";


 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be `echo`ing HTML from inside your classes that deal with the database - the job of that class is just to work with database related functionality, not the display of information.

You could return `false` from from your `insert` method, if a row for that user already exists and then output the HTML code from a different part of your application that deals with displaying a web page.

A similar, but slightly different approach, would be to throw an [exception](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). This could be caught in the code that calls the `insert` method and can then output some HTML.

Something like this would work:

```
try {
    $user->insert($userName, $email, $phone, $choise);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Add or output the error message where the rest of your HTML lives. 
}
```

You can make your own exceptions by creating a class that extends from PHPs `\Exception` class. This makes it easier to catch just the exception you are interested in.

You will need to output the HTML in the place that you want the message to be displayed on your page. That is one reason why it's good to separate working with the database and outputting HTML.

As a final note, you need to be careful about sanitising user-provided data that will be used in SQL statements. People can enter these values in a way that will allow them to execute queries in your database that you didn't want to allow. This is called SQL injection.[enter link description here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) As you're already using PDO, which is a good idea, have a look at how to do this securely using [parameter binding](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#example-1012).

Comment: thanks for your advises, I am using mvc4 and I have done the return statement within the insert method. so shall I echo the html from the controller or from the views

Comment: I would suggest you output the HTML in the view. You could pass a variable to the view that says whether the DB query was successful and use that to show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above hints I managed to solve the problem as following:

```
//I have added the return statement 
     public function insert($userName,$email,$phone,$choise) {       
     $dhandller = "SELECT `email`, `phone` FROM `info` WHERE email = '$email' OR phone = '$phone' ";
     $statements = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($dhandller);  
     $statements->execute(); 

     if ($statements->fetch() >= 1){  
        return FALSE;
     }else
     {
     $sqlQuerys = "INSERT INTO `oasis`.`info` VALUES ( '$userName', '$email', '$phone', '$choise')";
     $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuerys);  
     $statement->execute();  
    return TRUE;
     }
     }
```

Controller:

```
 if( $d->insert($firstname,$surename, $email,$choise) === TRUE){
  $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
  }  else {
      $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error  Please try again later</div>';
  }
```

//Views (HTML)

```
<?php echo $result; ?>
```